# Hi, I have two source tables one is emp (empno,ename,sal) and sal grade(grade,minsal,maxsal) tables

Tags: talend, talend-mdm

Source table is

```
emp
empno ename sal
101   abc   110
102   def   250
103   fgh   330
104   fff   220
105   rrr   190
```

sal grade

```
grade minsal  maxsal
a     100     200
b     201     300
c     301     400
```

output like

```
empno ename sal grade
101   abc   110  a
102   def   250  b
103   fgh   330  c
104   fff   220  b
105   rrr   190  a
```

How to implement in Talend?

Answer (score 1):

tMap is here for that:
[image]

Hope this helps,
TRF

Comment: Hi,  thanks for giving the information i can implement the this process but it can search each and every row it will display the 15 records .

Answer (score 1):

@hareesh,
Not at all because of the filter on tMap output flow.
Here is the result:

```
Starting job test at 14:30 09/11/2017.

[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3854
[statistics] connected
.-----+-----+---+-----.
|     tLogRow_12      |
|=----+-----+---+----=|
|empno|ename|sal|grade|
|=----+-----+---+----=|
|101  |abc  |110|a    |
|102  |def  |250|b    |
|103  |fgh  |330|c    |
|104  |fff  |220|b    |
|105  |rrr  |190|a    |
'-----+-----+---+-----'

[statistics] disconnected
Job test ended at 14:30 09/11/2017. [exit code=0]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for sharing information.Its working perfectly.

Comment: Hi,  Please send me the how to load incremental load or delta load in talend.processes

Comment: Question not clear. Seems to be an other subject. Open an other topic.